# cordova emulate android - qemu: could not load initrd ''

Tags: android, cordova, android-emulator

I'm compiling my first test app in my Linux Mint Android dev virtual machine following the example from http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/02/11/four-ways-to-build-a-mobile-app-part3-phonegap/
I got to the point when I'm trying to emulate android:

```
cordova emulate android
```

But it fails with:

```
qemu: could not load initrd ''
```

I googled it but didn't find much about this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I will solve my own issue.
So I realized that this issue is because it is trying to emulate ARM processor and no kernel image for that or something like that, so I started to wonder why ARM processor.

Long story short, I had to go back to the Android Virtual Device (AVD) Manager and edit the Android Virtual Device and change CPU/ABI from ARM to Intel Atom (x86) and now the error message is gone and the Android emulation loads.